# List of packages and their license

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a list of packages that also shows what license each package declares?

There is a list of available packages (eg. [for Hydro](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/hydro.html)).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141141/list-of-packages-and-their-license/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2014-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With a little bit of python you can get it from rosdistro (at least the licenses specified in package.xml):

```
curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/NikolausDemmel/9631654/raw/8b1a24909923eeac872a8c9b496e0c78930c4afc/hydro-licenses.py -s | python -
```

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've started making a bit more formal way to get a list of license for a given ROS package. Link to [the pull request](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rospkg/pull/133).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-02-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2